# FontAwesome icon onClick() event doesn’t work as expected

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am using the Font Awesome in my reach app.
I have added the required dependencies and imported them. The icons show up, unfortunately, when I click the icon directly, nothing happens.
Does anyone know why this happens, and how to fix it?

```js
clearHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

```html
<FontAwesomeIcon
    icon={['far', 'times-circle']}
    aria-hidden="true"
    onClick={this.clearHandler}
    className={styles.clearButton}
/>
```

Comment: Try to wrap your tag "FontAwesomeIcon" in a button tag, and set "onClick" on button.

Comment: I tried it but no luck

Comment: Try this, https://codesandbox.io/s/priceless-swartz-xqvyn

Comment: Please show more code.
If you are using a functional component and declared an event handler inside, then you don't need "this" key word.

Comment: I mean that onClick={clearHandler}

Comment: I will check and update you

Answer (score 1):

The onClick event definitely works, so I'm assuming you are adding the prevent default there so the click doesn't bubble up(??)

For this to work, you need to call `e.stopPropagation()` instead of `e.preventDefault()`.

See an example here: https://codesandbox.io/s/nice-sea-fjxnn

If you comment out line 7 and uncomment line 8, you will see the desired behavior (if that's what you need).

In any case, the `onClick` works just fine.